# SODA oracle 12 ,granting SODA_APP

Tags: java, json, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to grant SODA_APP role as per [SODA with JAVA](https://github.com/oracle/soda-for-java/blob/master/doc/Getting-started-example.md)

but this throws the following error in SQL developer

```
grant SODA_APP to IM_SIGIL_USR
Error report -
ORA-01924: role 'SODA_APP' not granted or does not exist
01924. 00000 -  "role '%s' not granted or does not exist"
*Cause:    Either the role was not granted to the user, or the role did not 
exist.
*Action:   Create the role or grant the role to the user and retry
 the operation.
```

Should there be any roles added while installation?

Comment: If you followed all the installation steps for the patch and the role is missing then you probably need to take it up with Oracle Support. Or just create it and move on. (I haven't used SODA myself though.)

Answer (score 1):

Which release are you on? If you're on 12.1.0.2 you need to install patch 20885778: https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=patch&id=20885778. That'll make the SODA_APP role available.

On subsequent releases, 12.2.0.1 and above, this is not required and SODA works out of the box, so you should be able to grant SODA_APP without having to install anything.